# Making a list of books that cover topics of a typical CS undergrad

Tags: computer-science

I want to cover the equivalent of a typical CS undergrad course in material, so I'm making a list of books to cover the typical topics. I've split the list into topics that, from the research I did, *I think* are compulsory and optional. I would like some help to confirm if the topics are split correctly, and if the books are of the correct level. Also, please let me know if I left out any important topics, or if any are beyond undergrad level.

Thank you for your time!

Edit regarding the on hold status: I do not believe this question is off-topic as I am not asking for a recommendation for books - I am asking if the *topics* I have listed are indicative of a typical CS course, and if any important topics are missing. The books links are only there in case the books I have chosen are not correct for the topic, and can be removed if necessary.

---

**COMPULSORY**

Operating Systems: [Operating System Concepts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118063333)

Networks: [Computer Networking: A Top-Down Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132856204)

Discrete Mathematics: [Concrete Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025)

Data Structures and Algorithms: [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844)

Computer Architecture: [Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136108040)

Automata Theory: [Introduction to the Theory of Computation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/113318779X)

Compilers: [Engineering a Compiler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/012088478X) was recommended to me over the dragon book.

Database Theory: [An Introduction to Database Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321197844)

Programming Language Concepts and Design: [Programming Language Pragmatics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123745144)

**OPTIONAL**

Cryptography: [Cryptography Engineering: Design Principles and Practical Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470474246)

Functional Programming: [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593272839)

Artificial Intelligence: [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136042597)

Computer Graphics: [Real-Time Rendering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814240)

Comment: Thank you for all this information.

Comment: As to Real-Time Rendering. the book is outdated, as more and more CG artists are moving toward free open source softwares like Blender. Some still use industrial softwares for filmmaking: examples like Maya, Houdini, and Studio Max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is very good on the subjects directly related to computer science. However, it is light on math. In my own B.Sc. in Computer Science I also had a ton of calculus, linear algebra, algebra (groups, rings, etc), statistics, analytic geometry and numerical analysis. Some applications of computer science rely heavily on those:

- Machine learning depends on lots of linear algebra, calculus, and statistics;
- Computer graphics depends a lot on analytic geometry and linear algebra;
- Scientific computation relies on calculus and numerical analysis.

I never used much of the ton of Algebra I had, but I hear it is important for cryptography. :-)

For a programmer developing more regular applications your list is very good, but for those interested in these more specialized areas (which are still pretty important), these subjects are vital.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :) It's good to have affirmation that the topics cover the field well.  I didn't mention that I have a Physics degree already, so I have covered the math side fairly well already, except for discrete math.

Comment: Excellent! Best of luck to you then! I did not mention that I also had to do two years of physics for my CS degree. I don't think it was very useful, but in any case you have that covered too, great. :-)